# MVVM: Mediator, Messenger

Tags: mvvm, mediator, messenger

I've recently downloaded the MVVMExtraLite and there is a helper called **Mediator**. I've heard of **Messenger** (in MVVM Light). Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the same pattern, Mediator. The Mediator in MVVMXL is more lightweight than Messenger in MVVML, the latter of which provides more types of messages and with generic.